# Can you make Would refer to earlier actions than the main clause's verb do?

Tags: modal-verbs

Earlier or at the same time, both would be fine to me. Can you make the title possible? Like this one below.

> I tried all the tools but the door wouldn't budge

In this, the Would refers to the actions that happened at the same time when 'I' tried.

But I want this request done with some restrictions.

1. Would for past habit.
2. Would not
3. Would have PP

Except those threes, can you do that?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I actually understand your question. Could you rephrase it, please.

Comment: Except that in your question something *didn't* happen when you tried it. It didn't budge. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @re_nez I just wanted to make the "clause(simple past verb), clause(would+verb)" where Would means the earlier actions than the 'simple past' in main clause. Not using those 3 above. I used No.2(would+not+verb) to make my example which have "(simple past),(would not verb)" in equal time line.

Comment: @re_nez The reason why I'm trying is that with just simple "would+verb", I thought, Would always means later actions such as "I said I would". I know I'm not clear when I said "actions" and it's more like intentions but anyway intentions for the posterior actions compared to the speaker's claim right? So I just wanted to know if there's an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried a number of get-your-door-to-budge tools because the door wouldn't budge.

There, **wouldn't budge** is used to refer to a fact that was temporally prior to the use of the tools.  The problem with the door existed prior to the attempt to fix it.

Comment: I appreciate that, but could you be nice and make an example with "would+verb"? Not just "would+not+verb". I just wanted to make the "clause(simple past verb)+ clause(would+verb)" where Would means the earlier actions than the 'simple past' in main clause.(or the same time). Not using those 3 above. I used No.2(would+not+verb) to make my example which have "(simple past),(would not verb)" in equal time line.

Comment: The reason why I'm trying is that with just simple "would+verb", I thought, Would always means later actions such as "I said I would". I know I'm not clear when I said "actions" and it's more like intentions but anyway intentions for the posterior actions compared to the speaker's claim right? So I just wanted to know if there's an exception.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. *She said she would like to visit London one day.*  There, **would** is referring to a wished for visit to London. Back then, she was looking forward.